# Powershell - json to text or csv

Tags: json, excel, csv, powershell

I have a folder with hundreds of json files in it & need to read them & create an output file with the various fields & values in it.

```
{
  "id": "02002010",
  "booktitle": "",
  "pagetitle": "Demo Page",
  "parent": "02002000",
  "img": [
    {
      "imgfile": "02A.png",
      "imgname": "02A.png"
    }
  ],
  "fmt": "",
  "entries": [
    {
      "itemid": "1",
      "partnumber": "1234567",
      "partdescription": "Washer",
      "partqty": "2",
      "Manufacturer": "ACME",
      "partdescriptionlocal": "Washer"
    },
    {
      "itemid": "2",
      "partnumber": "98765-B",
      "partdescription": "Screw",
      "partqty": "8",
      "Vendor": "Widget Inc",
      "TYPE": "Galv",
      "partdescriptionlocal": "Screw"
    }]
}
```

The json files will have generally the same structure, except that the "entries" may contain various fields in it that may not be the same from one entry to the next, or one json file to the next.  Some may have fields within entry that I do not know the name of.  There will be a few common fields in each "entries" section, but they could vary, and could be in a different order than what is shown.

I would like to write the output to a text/csv file that would be delimited that could then be imported into Excel.  One column header with all fields listed.  As new "entries" fields are found, tack them on to the end of each row & add to the header also.

Comment: I didn't see a question in there.

Comment: The issue is that JSON supports nested arrays, while CSV does not. What you are trying to do is not practical, and I would not advise it.

Answer (score 1):

you mean to do something like this?

```
$json = gc C:\temp\file.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$props = $json.entries | % {$_ | gm -MemberType NoteProperty} | select -exp name -Unique

$results = @()
foreach ($entry in $json.entries) {
    $obj = $json | select *
    foreach ($prop in $props) {
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $prop -Value $($entry | select -exp $prop -ea 0)
    }
    $results += $obj
}
$results | epcsv C:\temp\file.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
$results
```

Comment: Converting from Unicode to ASCII is lossy and entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @Anthony-Stringer - this sort of gives me something to work with.  I'm stuck right now on the "Select: cannot process argument because the value of argument 'obj' is null" which may be a bug.  But this generally gets what I really needed - the entries data - into a row & column format that I can use.

Comment: @TomBlodget should i use `-encoding default` instead?

Comment: UTF8 or Unicode[sic] (.NET should call this UTF16 like everybody else) would prevent data loss. But, only the requirements can say. Which encoding Default is depends on the OS and user settings so that unlikely to be a requirement. Actually, the potential data loss would occur in the first line due to the horrible default of [Get-Content](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847788.aspx).

Comment: Found something in the data I hadn't been expecting.  In one of the json files, I found "TYPE": null.   The Select -exp is having trouble handling them.  Others, it has no problem on, such as "Vendor":"" - just the ones with a null in them.